# .jfindclass error on R Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny-server, rjava, rjdbc

I have my shinyapp deployed on Shiny Server. I use `RJDBC::JDBC()` method to connect to Redshift DB.

RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar file is in the folder called "driver" which is in the same folder as app.R file, the argument 'driverClass' is "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver" and 'classPath' argument I provide is ".../driver/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar" but when I want to run the app in my browser, I get the following message (in browser):

> ## An error has occurred
>
> The application failed to start.
>
> The application exited during initialization.

In the log I find the following:

> Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
>   Calls: runApp ... ..stacktraceon.. -> JDBC -> is.jnull -> .jfindClass

I tried to set the CLASSPATH ('...' classified folders ):

> export CLASSPATH="/home/.../driver/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar"

but this does not work.

Please help.

Comment: you forget to put the .jar on the shiny server

Comment: well, I use WinSCP to upload files, and as I said .jar file is in the folder that is parallel to app.R, is there any other place I should put it?

Comment: you need to do `jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver",  classPath="the jar adress on shiny server" )`

Comment: yes, it is as you say, still does not work

Comment: you need to use \\ instead of `/` in the path

Comment: Solved. The problem was with Java version, when I checked it by
> library(rJava)
> jinit()
> .jcall("java/lang/System", "S", "getProperty", "java.runtime.version")

it turned out I needed Java 8, but provided Java 7

Answer (score 0):

put the diriver under /opt
make like /opt/driver/driver/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar
double check the path ... it is case sensitive